# how to specify date format in oracle while inserting record?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE
  (ROLLNO,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,CONTACT,CONTACT1,CONTACT2,ADDRESS,GRADE,DIVID,BLOOD_GROUP,HID,DATE_OF_BIRTH,TRANSPORT,SNAME,MEAL,BUSNO,RUTNO,DID,AID,CARD_TYPE,CARD_NO)
VALUES
 (135,'SHRENIK','ATUL','VAJPEYEE', 8852140367, 7698555412, 235599, 'LEN Q BEHIND DWARKA HOTEL', '9TH','40', 'AB-VE' ,13,'To_Date ('15-Aug-1997','dd-Mon-YYYY') ', 'NO' ,'DWARKA' ,'NO' ,'MH 04 3215' ,1,515,311, 'ESCORT' ,1062)
```

> 'To_Date ('15-Aug-1997','dd-Mon-YYYY') ',
>              *
>   ERROR at line 15:
>   ORA-00917: missing comma

But all commas are present and I need to specify this kind of date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO_DATE() is a function and not a string literal, so you need to remove the single quotes around it.

Comment: Private Sub CmdSave_Click()
sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE"
sql = sql + "VALUES ('To_Date ('" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "','dd-Mon-YYYY') '"
Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
******* I agreed but In vb6 It shows syntax error for to_date() using which I have to insert new  record.........please help

Comment: sir please suggest something

Comment: or this will work? <code>'" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "'</code>

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to put single quote to the `TO_DATE()` function.
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE (ROLLNO,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,CONTACT,CONTACT1,CONTACT2,ADDRESS,GRADE,DIVID,BLOOD_GROUP,HID,DATE_OF_BIRTH,TRANSPORT,SNAME,MEAL,BUSNO,RUTNO,DID,AID,CARD_TYPE,CARD_NO)

VALUES
 (135,'SHRENIK','ATUL','VAJPEYEE', 8852140367, 7698555412, 235599, 'LEN Q BEHIND DWARKA HOTEL', '9TH','40', 'AB-VE' ,13,To_Date('15-Aug-1997','dd-Mon-YYYY'), 'NO' ,'DWARKA' ,'NO' ,'MH 04 3215' ,1,515,311, 'ESCORT' ,1062)
```

Comment: But sir, I am trying to insert the record using vb6.....        record gets added in oracle if I remove the quotes from to_date() but in vb6 it shows syntax error.....                                                             thats why I am setting the quotes....

Comment: you can't write the query directly to your compiler. You have to pass the query string to a variable or run it directly like this: `sqlstrInsert = "[your query]"` then `dbconn.Execute (sqlstrInsert)`

Comment: @cool_sari, can you please give us your vb script on running/executing this query?

Comment: Private Sub CmdSave_Click()                                      sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE" sql = sql + "VALUES ('To_Date ('" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "','dd-Mon-YYYY') '"                                                     Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)                                          ******* I agreed but In vb6 It shows syntax error for to_date() using which I have to insert new record.........please help

Comment: considering your codes at your comment, you don't have spaces between the strings. You have to put spaces between the table name and the variables you use for example: `Private Sub CmdSave_Click() sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE <space> " sql = sql + "<space>VALUES (To_Date('" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "','dd-Mon-YYYY') '" Set RES = CON.Execute(sql) *******`

Comment: No sir,it is shown by this comment box,I am having proper code format as we write in vb,problem is that vb is not accepting the to_date format specified by me..................................

Comment: `TO_DATE()`function is not a vb function, it is an Oracle DB function.Try to run this code to your backend`INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE(ROLLNO,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,CONTACT,CONTACT1,CONTACT2,ADDRESS,GRADE,DIVID,BLOOD_GROUP,HID,DATE_OF_BIRTH,TRANSPORT,SNAME,MEAL,BUSNO,RUTNO,DID,AID,CARD_TYPE,CARD_NO)
VALUES(135,'SHRENIK','ATUL','VAJPEYEE', 8852140367, 7698555412, 235599, 'LEN Q BEHIND DWARKA HOTEL', '9TH','40', 'AB-VE' ,13,TO_DATE('15-Aug-1997','dd-Mon-YYYY'), 'NO' ,'DWARKA' ,'NO' ,'MH 04 3215' ,1,515,311, 'ESCORT' ,1062)` or maybe the error is not in the date format.

Comment: code gets executed in oracle but not in vb6 and I need to insert record using vb6 only..... So I specified this code format          <code>'" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & "'</code>                                                         it is accepting date bu at the time of retriving record it is showing error in date format....

Comment: I think the `DTPicker1` here is not the real source of your date string. Im not sure but in C#, you should get the date from the receiver of the date picker (ex TextBox txtDate) and it must be in format 'dd-MM-YYYY' then you can concat it directly to your query string.

Comment: how do you retrieve the data? Can you show us? or post it to another question.

Comment: <CODE>Private Sub CmbRNO_Click()
sql = "SELECT *FROM STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE WHERE ROLLNO ='" & CmbRNO.Text & "'"
Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
            DTPicker1.Value = RES!DATE_OF_BIRTH
           End Sub</code>
In this while compiling the code DATE_OF_BIRTH doesn't show any date where dtpicker shows default date,means DATE_OF_BIRTH field doesn't getting date from database.                                                            one important thing is it gives error only for the newly inserted record via vb6 not for already stored records......

Comment: to reverse the code from `insert` to `select` you have to use the `TO_CHAR()` function of Oracle.

Comment: @cool_sari, relax, I'm telling you how you should fetch your data from oracle so that you can handle it by your vb6 codes. You have to specify your fields like `SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'dd/MM/YYYY') FROM STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE`

Comment: @cool_sari, that should work. I'm suggesting that you should specify your fields. Don't just use `SELECT * `. All queries I posted are working.